# Updating nodes in a SpriteKit scene from an outside UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit

How can I update SpriteKit Scene from outside the scene itself. E.g. how do I update a SKLabelNode by pressing a UIButton.

**Scene**

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var myLabel:SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        myLabel.text = "Initial State"
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }

    func didPressButton() {
        myLabel.text = "Pressed! "
    }
```

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func didPressButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            scene.didPressButton()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

    …

}
```

I understand that the usual `touchesBegan` inside the scene works just fine for updating the SKLabelNode inside the scene. But I am specifically interested in updating the scene from outside events. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the file where is your button:

```
protocol PauseBtnSelectorDelegate {
    func didPressPauseBtn(pauseBtn:SKSpriteNode)
}

class HUD: SKNode {
    var pauseBtnDelegate:PauseBtnSelectorDelegate?
    var pauseBtn :SKSpriteNode!
    ...
    func pauseBtnTap(sender:SKSpriteNode) {
        print("pauseBtn touched")
        pauseBtnDelegate!.didPressPauseBtn(sender)
    }
}
```

In the file where you want to notify the tap event:

```
class GameScene: SKScene,PauseBtnSelectorDelegate {
    var hud: HUD!
   ...
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)
         // Adding HUD
        self.hud = HUD(currentScene: self,nodeSize: self.frame.size)
        self.hud.pauseBtnDelegate = self
        self.addChild(hud)
    }

    func didPressPauseBtn(pauseBtn:SKSpriteNode) {
        print("pauseBtn touched")
        // Pause the game
    }
}
```